# Is there a way to transform a json dictionary into a table in Azure DataFlow?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have as source a simple json dictionary like this that I want to process with Azure Data Factory. In this example there are two objects with dynamic names: Type1 and Type2, but in the real case there could be much more

```
{
    "TYPE": {
        "Type1": {
            "ADD": 5,
            "UPDATE": 0,
            "REMOVE": 2
        },
        "Type2": {
            "ADD": 2,
            "UPDATE": 2,
            "REMOVE": 1
        }
    }
}
```

With an Azure Data Flow transformation, I would like to obtain a tabular structure like this:

| TYPE | ADD | UPDATE | REMOVE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Type1 | 5 | 0 | 2 |
| Type2 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

Parse or Flatten transformation doesn't seem to fit in this case.
I Tried with a derived column, using this expression:
`byPath('TYPE.Type1')`

This brings a partial result, it works only for 1 object. What I really need is to obtain the properties for all the objects without knowing in advance their names
[image]

Maybe if there is a grouping function to sum up the properties Add, Update and Remove of all the objects to obtain something like this, this will solve my issue as well.

| ADD | UPDATE | REMOVE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 2 | 3 |

Thanks in advance for any answer.